# Does GetOrAdd wait if it's busy on retrieving a value with same key?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

Consider this code:

```
void DoSomething(int key)
{
    concurrentDictionary.GetOrAdd(key, (k)=>
        {
            //Do some expensive over network and database to retrieve value.
        });
```

Consider 2 threads are invoking `DoSomething(2)`. At the same time they will see that there's no item with `Key==2` in the dictionary. Consider `Thread1` starts doing the expensive algorithm to retrieve the value of 2.

**Question 1:** Will `Thread2` waits for `Thread1` to accomplish its job? Or simply tries to retrieve the value itself, and throwing it away at the time of adding it to the dictionary? (As the `Thread1` added this already )

**Question 2:** If `Thread2` doesn't wait, what's the best solution to avoid multiple running of that expensive algorithm?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It tells you in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378677%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> If you call `GetOrAdd` simultaneously on different threads, *addValueFactory* may be called multiple times, but its key/value pair might not be added to the dictionary for every call.

For question 2, I'd consider changing from a `ConcurrentDictionary<int,Something>` to a `ConcurrentDictionary<int,Lazy<Something>>` where the `addValueFactory` method simply constructs a [`Lazy<Something>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that specifies the [`ExecutionAndPublication`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.lazythreadsafetymode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) mode. The expensive operation would then by the `valueFactory` for the `Lazy<Something>`

Comment: Thanks. The only problem that still remains is, when to initialize the Lazy itself? As multiple threads should use a same Lazy<Something> instance.

Comment: You create the `Lazy<Something>` inside your `addValueFactory`. Now, multiple instances of the `Lazy<Something>` might be created, but only *one* of them will ever actually end up in the dictionary, and that same one will be the only one which is returned by the `GetOrAdd` method.

Answer (score 2):

> Consider 2 threads are invoking DoSomething(2). **At the same time they
>   will see that there's no item with Key==2 in the dictionary.**

<s>I don't think the scenario in bold is possible, that would be a race condition. The check-for-a-key operation is protected by a lock mechanism inside `GetOrAdd`. Whichever thread acquires the lock first will have the chance to add the key/value. The other thread will be waiting blocking and then will just obtain that value, once `GetOrAdd` has released the lock acquired by the first thread.</s>

I was wrong. The [answer by @Damien_The_Unbeliever](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21572484/1768303) is correct. Below is how `GetOrAdd` implementation looks like. The lock only takes place inside `TryGetValue` and `TryAddInternal`. I'd be very interested to know the background behind such design decision.

```
public TValue GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func<TKey, TValue> valueFactory)
{
    TValue local;
    if (key == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
    }
    if (valueFactory == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("valueFactory");
    }
    if (!this.TryGetValue(key, out local))
    {
        this.TryAddInternal(key, valueFactory(key), false, true, out local);
    }
    return local;
}
```

Comment: I too think it's an odd decision on their part - if computing the value was so cheap, you'd expect people to use the overload that directly accepts a value rather than a value factory.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever they likely did this to avoid deadlocks when user code is called under a lock. For example the factory could call back into the dictionary. The BCL people are very conservative and they rarely call user code under a lock (I have actually never seen it).

Comment: @usr With another point of view, this design decision seems OK too, as it's hard to put lock for values separately! For example: If it's retrieving value of key=2 and the other thread want value for key=3, it shouldn't wait for key=2 and add another lock for key=3 so the other threads wait if need for key=3

Comment: @mehrandvd the locks are striped. Each key is assigned to a lock stripe. Only keys in the same lock stripe conflict. That's a random and rare occurrence. Most of the time, access to different keys is independent.